# background color doesn't stretch full height of div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-color

I have a section that is wrapping **2 div’s**, one a video and the other a block of text.  In the text block, I want the **background color** to **span the height** of the div, which appears to be a function of the height of the video.  I would rather not use absolute pixel values to declare the height of the div.   A height of 500px is very close but it’s impossible to get the top and bottom margins of both the video and text divs perfectly aligned.

**Question:**
Is there any way to make the background color in the text div span the entire div without declaring a height?

Since the black background of the wrapper is doing so, and neither the wrapper or the div's have a declared height, it seems like there should be a way.  Thank you.

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.container_white_space {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

.container_white_space p {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper_video_and_text {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.video {
  width: 50%;
}

.video_text {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(80, 70, 81));
}

.video_text p {
  font-family: "europa", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 135%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/libraries/YQ8opLwo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/qkv6kzb.js"></script>
    <script>
      try {
          Typekit.load({
              async: true
          });
      } catch (e) {}
    </script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/qkv6kzb.js"></script>
    <script>
      try {
          Typekit.load({
              async: true
          });
      } catch (e) {}
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Barton's website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div class="container_white_space">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <section class="wrapper_video_and_text">
      <div class="video">
        <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload>
          <source src="https://bartonlewisfilm.com/08-LHBExcerpt.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="video_text">
        <p>text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="container_white_space">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the 2nd div with text to streach the white background? but the text will be still in the middle or just center the text starting from the to top?

Comment: No.  I want the 2nd div with text to maintain the same relationship with the white backgrounds above and below it.  I just want the color to fill the 2nd div (replacing the black background presently there) so that the color is equal to the vertical dimensions of the video to its left.

Comment: Okay. so you just want to change the **black background** in second div to **white**? Am I right?

Comment: No.  The 2nd div has a linear-gradient - a colored background.  It's presently evident only surrounding the text block.  I want it to fill the entire div with the class of "video_text" (top to bottom and left to right).

Comment: Yes, I saw it its a linear-gradient. Please try my answer and tell me if this is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the margin:auto from the class .video-text and add min-height:100%

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Barton's website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        html {
            background-color: black;
        }
        body {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto 0;
        }
        .container_white_space {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .container_white_space p {
            text-indent: -9999px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .wrapper_video_and_text {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 0px;
        }
        .video {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .video_text {
            width: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(80, 70, 81));
            min-height:100%;

        }
        .video_text p {
            font-family: "europa",sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: black;
            line-height: 135%;
            margin-left: 30%;
            margin-right: 30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<div class="container_white_space">
    <p>text</p>
</div>
<section class="wrapper_video_and_text">
    <div class="video">
        <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload>
            <source src="https://bartonlewisfilm.com/08-LHBExcerpt.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video_text">
        <p>text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here.</p>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="container_white_space">
    <p>text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting.  That also works.  I don't think you can mark 2 answers as correct so I'll stay with the first one, but thank you.

Comment: I switched the correct answer to no. 2 from no. 1 as the no.1 method moved the linear gradient to the entire wrapper, so that the color was lighter by the time it entered the frame in the text div than it should be.  No. 2 method confines the gradient to the text div.  Thank you for your help & my apologies Bluetree for not catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Just move your background color from

`.video_text` to `.wrapper_video_and_text`

**Do this**

```
.wrapper_video_and_text{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(80, 70, 81));
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.container_white_space {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

.container_white_space p {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper_video_and_text {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(80, 70, 81));
}

.video {
  width: 50%;
}

.video_text {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video_text p {
  font-family: "europa", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 135%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/libraries/YQ8opLwo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/qkv6kzb.js"></script>
    <script>
      try {
          Typekit.load({
              async: true
          });
      } catch (e) {}
    </script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/qkv6kzb.js"></script>
    <script>
      try {
          Typekit.load({
              async: true
          });
      } catch (e) {}
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Barton's website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div class="container_white_space">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <section class="wrapper_video_and_text">
      <div class="video">
        <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload>
          <source src="https://bartonlewisfilm.com/08-LHBExcerpt.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="video_text">
        <p>text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here text goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="container_white_space">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Holy smokes, I swear I tried that and it didn't work.  God only know what happened.  Anyway, this is exactly what I want.  Thanks very much!!

Comment: Try to clear cache your browser. Sometimes for some reason when you change your CSS or JS  it doesn't update in your browser so that's why you don't see the changes. Just Clear some cache :)

Comment: not sure what upvote means, but i did accept as correct.  let me know if i need to do anything else.